# use tee command to redirect output to a file in a non-existent dir

Tags: linux, shell, unix, tee

I am trying to use the tee command to redirect output to a file, and I want the file to be created in a dir which is yet to be created.

```
date | tee new_dir/new_file
```

when new_dir is not there, the tee command fails saying

> tee: new_dir/new_file: No such file or directory

If I create the new_dir prior to running the tee command, then it works fine, but for some reason I don't want to create the new_dir manually, is it possible to create the new_dir with the tee command ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No. You'll have to create the directory before running `tee`.

Comment: The directory already exists in my case, but tee complains that the file does not exist, if I do not use the -a flag with tee.

Answer (score 9):

Replace `tee` with a function that creates the directory for you:

```
tee() { mkdir -p ${1%/*} && command tee "$@"; }
```

If you want the function to work when invoked with a simple file name:

```
tee() { if test "$1" != "${1%/*}"; then mkdir -p ${1%/*}; fi &&
   command tee "$1"; }
```

Comment: `tee foo.txt` => `mkdir -p foo.txt && command tee "foo.txt"` I don't think that's quite right...

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir ./new_dir && date | tee ./new_dir/new_file
```

Since it is `tee` command, it simultaneously writes both to the `new_file` and to `stdout`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... After some experiments, I've found some interesting things.

First of all, let's try to touch some file:

```
touch ~/.lein/profiles.clj
```

It works fine. But let's use the same thing with quotes:

```
touch "~/.lein/profiles.clj" # => touch: cannot touch ‘~/.lein/profiles.clj’: No such file or directory
```

So, for my bash function:

```
append_to_file() {
  echo $2 | tee -a $1
}
```

after that I changed call from it:

```
append_to_file '~/.lein/projects.clj' '{:user {:plugins [[lein-exec "0.3.1"]]}}'
```

to it (first argument without quotes):

```
append_to_file ~/.lein/projects.clj '{:users {:plugins [[lein-exec "0.3.1"]]}}'
```

And all is well.

UPDATE

This case considers `.lein` as existing directory.

Comment: `touch "~/.lein/profiles.clj"` fails because double quotes inhibit tilde-expansion.