# tee - if file doesn't exist do nothing

Tags: bash, tee

I try to save echo command to log file:

```
echo "XXXXX" | tee -a ./directory_with_logs/my_script.log
```

It works well when file my_script.log exist

```
XXXXX
```

(XXXXX was written to my_script.log also)

When my_script.log doesn't exist I got something like this

```
tee: ./directory_with_logs/my_script.log: No such file or directory
XXXXX
```

I tried if else procedure to check if files exist and then write to log

```
function saveLog(){ 
if [[ -e "./directory_with_logs/my_script.log" ]] ; then 
tee -a ./directory_with_logs/my_script.log 
fi ; } 
echo "XXXXX" | saveLog
```

but it works wrong also when file doesn't exist, there nothing happens in xterm, no echo command

How to print in xterm and write to log file echo command,

or only print in xterm when log file doesn't exist?

Please help :)

Comment: Is the issues that the *file* doesn't exist or that the *directory* doesn't? Because those aren't the same thing. `tee` should create the file just fine but it will not create the directory.

Comment: That's it. Also related [use tee command to redirect output to a file in a non-existent dir](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14236621/1983854).

Comment: Also, what's wrong with simply doing `echo "XXXXXX" >> ./directory_with_logs/my_script.log`??? Why invoke `tee` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work, is that when the file doesn't exist, it does not consume the standard input. You can fix it by adding a `cat` call in the `else` branch like this:

```
saveLog() { 
  if [[ -e "./directory_with_logs/my_script.log" ]] ; then 
    tee -a ./directory_with_logs/my_script.log 
  else
    cat
  fi 
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You don't need tee to append a file thats what >> is for

try this:

```
echo "XXXXX" >> ./directory_with_logs/my_script.log
```

Comment: He is probably using `tee -a` because he wants to *see* the output, as well as append to the file.